# Is this link in a question a shameless plug?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, spam

A while ago I answered **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727102/how-to-use-sass-in-visual-studio-2013)** question. I've since contemplated editing the question to remove the 2013 versioning so it applies to all versions of Visual Studio as my answer reflects and thus helping more people.

When I started the edit I noticed that the "My Question is" text is hyperlinked to a Persian language page about baby milk?

Even if this is the site the OP wanted to use SASS to develop, it essentially has nothing to do with the question? The cynical part of me thinks its a shameless plug designed to increase link sharing and SEO rankings for the baby milk site, but should I edit the question to remove it? Should I use comments to open a dialogue with the OP to find out what the link is for and why he edited his post to add the link? At the end of the day, it's not doing any harm, so shall I just leave it or get rid?

Comment: I have no idea what the link was about, but I rolled it back to your edit and then edited out parts further

Comment: Very weird, investigating this user's edit and question history does not seem to yield other similar results. I'm guessing it was a prank of sorts? This user should be notified with a link to this Meta.

Comment: @Kyll - Save yourself some time - [Their latest revisions list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1897577/radian?tab=activity&sort=revisions) shows a few different similar edits, [i rolled back one more](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32679466/revisions) but this is more something for a mod to do further.

Comment: @Sayse Ah, indeed, but only on that single question..? Strange.

Comment: @Kyll - [Another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27985154/1324033) (that I haven't edited), I couldn't see any more but then its still a repeat offender

Comment: @Sayse Ah, right. Has a moderator flag been raised by anyone yet?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure how to proceed so no, I've not raised any flags.

Comment: I'm raising a flag then... Done.

Comment: Yes, I raised a custom flag (after my spam flag on the question mentioned by @ChrisSpittles was *declined*, because the spam link was already edited out - one more reason *not to edit* spam posts!)

Comment: A link to baby milk ? Seems like that account has been compromised no ? Is this regular on SO, having our account compromised and used to propagate spam ?

Comment: Not spam, just a programmer that's happy/proud about how it turned out.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems the user [*deliberately* inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20727102/revisions) the link ([to their own website!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27985154/1324033)) into the post, at a time when the question already had a score of [±50](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20727102/timeline). I think that qualifies as spam, so while editing it out is a temporary solution, we should not tolerate this kind of behaviour here, especially (as @Sayse found out) the same happened to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679466/cant-create-foreign-key-in-mysql-wordpress).

Comment: I know you've edited it out of your answer now, but you're right, the second example I found is asking about the website (which is why I didn't edit that one) but the question would still stand on its own without the links :)

Comment: @Sayse in that case, I felt it was justified to include a link to their website.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @Sayse and Glorfindal.

Comment: Before everyone starts piling on this person and declares them a spammer, I should note that they've been a member of this site for four years and had done nothing to cause a problem before this. They did declare it was a site they were working on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985154/star-rating-rich-snippet-is-not-working-correctly-in-google-search), and it's common for people to link to their in-development websites in an attempt to provide context to their question. I'm going to give them the benefit of the doubt and assume the link was an accident in the question above.

Comment: @Glorfindel - Agree with Brad. If there's no chronic behavior from the user, then the spam probably came from another source. Maybe even a bug or injection allowed someone else to change it so the edit has no history or the provenance of the edit is inaccurate.

Comment: Why are all the links links to removed posts in this answer and question? :P

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is off-topic per the help:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

The question is **not** asking how to use a tool/software library, it's asking for tools/software libraries to use, especially considering the answers..